# BI Publisher and Excel template Preview Error

Tags: oracle

I am using Excel (2013) and have the BI publisher add on.  I load the sample data, and to preview I am getting the below:
Please advise, thanks James

Start Excel Preview
only open: false
mTemplate: C:\Users\AJCENTROID\AppData\Local\Oracle\BIPublisher\TemplateBuilderforExcel\tmp\tmp\tmp.xls
mTmpTemplate: C:\Users\AJCENTROID\AppData\Local\Oracle\BIPublisher\TemplateBuilderforExcel\tmp/tmp.xls
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.xdo.template.excel.ExcelController.processActionLanguage(ExcelController.java:364)
    at oracle.xdo.template.excel.ExcelController.process(ExcelController.java:256)
    at oracle.xdo.template.ExcelProcessor.process(ExcelProcessor.java:244)
    at ExcelPreview.runXDO(ExcelPreview.java:110)
    at ExcelPreview.main(ExcelPreview.java:87)

Answer (score 2):

As a response for your request, i know that it becomes late but may be that can help some people else, just try to empty that temp directory (C:\Users\AJCENTROID\AppData\Local\Oracle\BIPublisher\TemplateBuilderforExcel\tmp). I tried it several times and it works nickel for me. Hope that helps !

Regards,
Moussa